# run php script and return data as a string

Tags: php, file-get-contents

My php script needs to load contents from another file and then replace certain commands. Using the following code works on static pages:

```
$pageName = 'pages/' . $_REQUEST['url'] . '.php';

$pageContents = file_get_contents($pageName);

$IDCODE = $_SESSION['IDCODE'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE IDCODE = '$IDCODE'";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);

$OK = $qry ? true : false;

$arr = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

foreach ($arr AS $key => $val) {
$pageContents = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $val, $pageContents);
}
```

however, what if the file to be processed was dynamic? IE it populates some text from the mysql database.

Will file_get_contents run the file or just read whats in it as a string?

Comment: It will not run it as php unless you called it with the full URL (i.e. `file_get_contents('http://yoursite.com/pages/' . $_REQUEST['url'] . '.php');`  Though this may pose some security risks unless $_REQUEST['url'] is sanitized and validated.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the link to the file via a webserver, it will be processed. If you link it directly, you will get the exact contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Rather messy code.

> $pageName = 'pages/' . $_REQUEST['url'] . '.php';
>
> $pageContents = file_get_contents($pageName);

local file inclusion vulnerability here.

> $OK = $qry ? true : false;

Why? Anywere you use the value of $OK you could equally use $qry. And you never use $OK again in the code shown.

There's no error checking, no comments in the code.

> what if the file to be processed was dynamic?

WTF? Do you mean you want to re-process the output as PHP? Then you could 'eval($pageContents);' but beware of code injection vulnerabilities.

Or you want to apply your script to the output of a PHP scrpt? Then just pass the URL as the argument to file_get_contents() e.g.

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost/path/' 
         . basename($_REQUEST['url'] . '.php');
```

But really the invocation should be controlled better than this. Both are messy solutions - a templating solution should be just that. Go have a long hard look at (e.g.) smarty

Comment: I've used smarty before. I do us $OK later on but I just dont have it posted. I have other error checks that affect $OK. I tried using require($pageName) and it works fine.